# How can i make a slider scrollable by dragging?

Tags: javascript, slider, draggable

[I want to create a slider like this, with arrows to show the next/previous elements, and with the feature to make horizontal scroll by dragging the finger/mouse to left and right. I am looking for and easy solution, with no libraries, just javascript.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ7PJ.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EventListeners, for non-mobile devices you’d use "mousedown","mousemove" etc.

```
const myslider = document.querySelector('your-slider-name');

myslider.addEventListener(“mousemove” (e) =>  {
//add your code for scrolling 
});
```

have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mousemove_event) which explains in more depth